# Do pods of the same deployment share the same certificate when using Istio mTLS

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar, mtls

When enabling mTLS in Istio, every pod of a given deployment has a certificate.

My question is: do pods of the same deployment share the same certificate or it's different for every pod?

Answer (score 1):

It is a different certificate for every pod. But having different certificates doesn't matter as the information encoded into them is the same (the SPIFFE ID is encoded into them and for pods of the same deployment it is the same ID).